# Scope and compile undefined in Angularjs directive test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to create a few tests for this directive. The first being that a keydown event with an alpha character should not change the value of the element. Here is the directive.

```
// PhoneInput directive for formatting phone input.
angular.module('app')
    .directive('phoneInput', function ($filter, $browser) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                var listener = function () {
                    var value = $element.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    $element.val($filter('tel')(value, false));
                };

                // This runs when we update the text field
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    return viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0, 10);
                });

                // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
                ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                    $element.val($filter('tel')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
                };

                $element.bind('change', listener);
                $element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
                    var key = event.keyCode;
                    // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
                    // This lets us support copy and paste too
                    if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
                });

                $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
                    $browser.defer(listener);
                });
            }

        };
});
```

Loosely following [this guide](http://coffeedriven.org/angularjs-testing-keydown-listener/), I created the following this test for the keydown of an alpha.

```
describe('phoneInput directive', function() {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

   // Define global references for injection
    var scope, compile, document, element, template;
    element = null;

    // making an input element that calls phoneInput
    template = 'input required name="tel" ng-model="tel" type="text" phone-input >';


    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $document) {
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        document = $document;
    }));

    beforeEach(function(){
        element = compile(template)(scope);
        // spyOn keyDown
        spyon(scope, 'keydown');
    });

    it('should not accept alpha characters', function(){
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(compile);
       var givenEvent = {keyCode: 65};
       scope.$digest();

       element.triggerHandler('keydown', givenEvent);

       expect(element.val()).toEqual('');
    });
});
```

The issue is that the test prints the error that both scope and compile are undefined. You see that there is a console.log for both scope & compile, upon testing they both spit undefined.

Comment: In the example you linked, they're passing in the $injector into their `beforeEach(inject(function([...]` and doing `scope     = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();`, but you're just doing `scope = rootScope.$new();`. Did you try following the example exactly in that regard?

Comment: Should this 'scope = rootScope.$new();' be 'scope = $rootScope.$new();'?
$ before rootScope is missing.
Also, is the template missing the opening tag (<)?

Comment: @Spitfire good point, however it doesn't fix the issue when I tried it.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @sphanley I have tried both ways of doing it. It doesn't make a difference. And I assume they essentially do the same thing.

Comment: @Spitfire I will try to get one up and running.